# How to send an email to 2 persons from a table at the same time using php

Tags: php, mysql, email

I'm getting trouble with my php code. 
I have a table named: prof_ales with 3 columns: cnp, evaluat and evaluator.

And a button "Send Email".
When the client press the button I want to send an email to 2 specific email adresses which are already saved into my table "prof_ales" in the column "evaluator".

Here is my code, and for now it's working, but the message is send **only at the last** email adress.

```
    <input class="buttom" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Send Email" type="submit">  



<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$interogare = ("SELECT * FROM prof_ales  WHERE cnp='".$_SESSION['sess_user']."'");
$rezultat = mysql_query($interogare);
while ($rand = mysql_fetch_assoc($rezultat)) {
$ev= $rand['evaluat'];
$to = $rand['evaluator'];
}

$message = "test email ";
$subject = "Received from $ev"; 
$body = <<<EMAIL
 Etc etc

$message

Bla Bla 

EMAIL;

$header = "From: quabits.ro";
}
if($_POST){
mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
echo "Sent";
}
?>
```

As I said I want to send to both(or more) email adresses any time when button is pressed. Tks.

Comment: Can you send email to one person. If so just do it again but change the address

Comment: It's not a solution to me. If you are a client on my website and want to send that email you don't have the permisions to the database or code to change the email adress. So it's not a solution.

Comment: @user3718552 - move the email sending code to inside your `while` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said above you need to put the call of the `mail()` function inside the `while()`-loop. Using correct formating makes the code easier to read:

```
while ($rand = mysql_fetch_assoc($rezultat)) {
    $ev= $rand['evaluat'];
    $to = $rand['evaluator'];
    $message = "test email ";
    $subject = "Received from $ev"; 
    $body = "Test";
    $header = "From: quabits.ro";
    if($_POST) {
        mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must put the code to send the email *in* the while loop. So it would be:

```
    <?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("","","","");
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $interogare = ("SELECT * FROM prof_ales  WHERE cnp='".$_SESSION['sess_user']."'");
    $rezultat = mysqli_query($interogare,$connect);
    while ($rand = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezultat)) {
    $ev= $rand['evaluat'];
    $to = $rand['evaluator'];

    $message = "test email ";
    $subject = "Received from $ev"; 
    $body = <<<EMAIL
     Etc etc

    $message

    Bla Bla 

    EMAIL;

    $header = "From: quabits.ro";
    }
    if($_POST){
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
    echo "Sent";
    }
    }
    ?>
```

The code you wrote just meant:

> select the first email from database and save it into a variable.
>   Replace the value into the variable with the second email. Send a mail
>   to the address in the variable.

The improved version means:

> select the first email from database and save it into a variable. Send a mail to the address in the variable.
>   Replace the value into the variable with the second email. Send a mail
>   to the address in the variable.

Comment: I tried, but it's not working. Stil the same problem. Email sent only at last adress.

Comment: Check if your hosting provider limits the number of emails sendable every second

Comment: If you are limited by your provider and PHP's mail function, you can try something like PHPMailer (very popular, https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). It will let you send via SMTP etc.  Just another option if you are limited by your setup.

Comment: I don't know where to check this but, my website is hosted by http://www.000webhost.com/ and it's a free license. I think this should not be a problem.

Comment: Usually free hosting providers limit the number of sendable emails to avoid spam. As @brechmos said, you can use phpmailer to solve the problem.